# What would cause event.dataTransfer.files to be null in IE10?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-10

So, given this code:

```
var container = document.getElementById("body");
container.addEventListener("dragenter", noopHandler, false);
container.addEventListener("dragover", noopHandler, false);
container.addEventListener("drop", function(evt) {
    noopHandler(evt);
    console.log('drop');
    console.log(evt.dataTransfer.files);
}, false);
```

In Chrome and FF, evt.dataTransfer.files contains all the files the user dropped on the page.

But in IE10, there is no evt.dataTransfer.files. The FileList object doesn't exist at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: It works fine for me in IE 10.0.9200.16618

Comment: 1. You are sure you are on an official release of IE10? Just checking, because dataTransfer.files was added in Preview 2, so it's technically possible to have "IE10" without the files.

2. If you use a regular `<input id="file" type="file" multiple>`, does `document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', function () { console.log(this.files); }, false);` get you the files list?

Comment: I had a similar problem. Hopefully, [this][1] can help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19094779/1088805

Answer (score 1):

dataTransfer.files does exist in IE10, it's even documented on the IE dev center : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh580307(v=vs.85).aspx

You probably have a javascript error or something that is not necessarily related ot his. What you could do though, is check if the FileList object exists.

```
if(typeof FileList !== 'undefined')
```

This should be true if the FileList exists in your browser. If it returns false, that means you're probably not using IE10.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late for an answer, but you might want to check that compatibility view is off.  In IE9 and below dataTransfer doesn't exist, and using any of the console tools that change browser rendering removes the files object from dataTransfer.