# IE 10 drag and drop upload gives empty dataTransfer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I have some drag and drop upload code that isn't working properly in IE 10. My event handlers look something like this:

```
dragCatcher.on('drop', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);
}).on('dragenter', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}).on('dragleave', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}).on('dragover', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.types);
});
```

Both `console.log`'s come up with `undefined`. I can confirm it's not a console bug, as `e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0]` comes up with an error. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem today. After 5 hours debugging, I found this from my`<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

After I change it to IE=10, problem solved. (Make sure you restart your IE)

Hopefully, this can solve your problem too.

Comment: Wow that...okay, well. That's silly, but it worked. Though it seems the data IE 10 gives me back on the drop event is...curious. It looks like the file name `test.txt` becomes `test.txt.txt`, which hardly seems right.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that the whole concept of dataTransfer object as part of the event instance is deprecated in IE, as documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535861%28v=vs.85%29.aspx It explains why the accepted answer works, since it makes IE 10 to "downgrade" itself

Comment: @Lei Zhao --> Thank you, your advice worked for me too!